# Using a USB barcode scanner under Linux which sends characters using Alt + ASCII (hex unicode)

Tags: linux, keyboard

I am trying to use a USB barcode scanner (with HID emulation) under Linux which sends some characters (such as <kbd>[</kbd>) using <kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by the ascii value. This works fine under Windows of course but I’m want to use it under Linux as well.

I’ve been trying to reprogram the device but no matter what language and settings I use it keeps sending using <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Is there a way to either enable this behavior? Perhaps by somehow rebinding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and have it accepting decimal ASCII instead of hex unicode?

Comment: Most barcode scanners I've seen allow you to program it by scanning specific manufacturer barcodes.  Can you include the scanner model number and maybe we can find the exact barcode you need to change the configuration.

Comment: Champ SD1003, I have a physical copy of Bar Code Configuration Guide v3.7 and tried most of the settings in it.